# Deselecting an item in listview is triggering selection event

Tags: java

```
loop: while((token=t.get_token())!=null)
{
t.remove(token);
System.out.println("token: "+token);
if(b.is_san_move_legal(token))
{
b.list.getSelectionModel().select(token);
```

So I have a listview in which I select a specific token. Then in another class, the class of object 'b', has a list selection event change listener.

```
list.setItems(items);

list.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new 
ChangeListener<String>() {

@Override
public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String 
oldValue, String newValue) {
// Your action here
if(newValue != null) {
ObservableList<String> selectedItems =  
list.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();


for(String s : selectedItems){
System.out.println(s);
make_san_move(s,true); 
}
}

}
});
```

The problem is everytime make_san_move is called the listview needs to change however the selection seems to still be attached to the previous selection and even though the selection has not changed make_san_move is triggered again with the same selection object.  How do I fix that.

Comment: That's an expected behavior, there are attributes on the triggered event that allows you to distinguish between deselect and select

Comment: What do you mean? If the listview changes with list.setitems(items) will that cause a deselect? and if so why is it still triggering the event and causing the same object to pass the the observableList and for loop?